# jquery all.parent().not(/*first parent*/).data('bar') returns undefined from the third parent onwards

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out this problem since yesterday, and looks like a bug in jquery.

I'm writing a sorting script, there's a `<header>` with four columns (`<li>`) and each has a `<span>`, the ones I'm clicking to sort the data. I want the first `<span>` to reset the sorting when one of the other three columns are sorting (have a `data-sortby` attribute), so I need a condition (`var isSet` checks if any of the three `<span>` has the data attribute `sortby`):

```js
// defaults (needed for getJSON())
var sort = 'coinranking',  // this is data-sorton
    order = 'desc'  // this is data-sortby

$(function() {

    $(document).on('click', 'article#coin-ranking > header > ul > li > span', function() {

        sort = $(this).data('sorton')

        var self = $(this),
            all = $('article#coin-ranking > header > ul > li > span'),
            isSet = all.parent().not('li.coin-profile').find('span').data('sortby')
        console.log(all);
        console.log(self);
        console.log(self.data('sortby')); // no problem here, as expected
        all.removeClass()
        all.not(this).removeData('sortby')
        console.log(isSet) // problem: returns undefined when it shouldn't
        if (self.data('sortby') === 'asc' || (self.parent().hasClass('coin-profile') && isSet)) {
            self.addClass('desc')
            order = sort === 'coinranking' ? 'desc' : 'asc'
            self.data('sortby', 'desc')
        }
        else {
            self.addClass('asc')
            order = sort === 'coinranking' ? 'asc' : 'desc'
            self.data('sortby', 'asc')
        }

        //getJSON().then(LoadHomeList)

    })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article id="coin-ranking">

    <header>

        <ul>

            <li class="coin-profile"><span data-sorton="coinranking" aria-label="sort">Cryptocurrency</span></li>
            <li class="coin-marketcap"><span data-sorton="marketCap" aria-label="sort">Market Cap</span></li>
            <li class="coin-price"><span data-sorton="price" aria-label="sort">Price</span></li>
            <li class="coin-change"><span data-sorton="change" aria-label="sort">24H Change</span></li>

        </ul>

    </header>

    <ul></ul>

    <footer></footer>

</article>
```

So if I click the `<span>` from the second `<li>` a couple of times, then I get the expected value printed in console (the last two console.log() return as expected). The problem starts from the third `<li>` onwards, if I click those `<span>` then the last console.log() returns undefined, but the one before returns the expected value (the one set in the if/else).

Clearly the problem lies in `var isSet`.

I've also prepared a fiddle that shows the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/chazy/su104cqz/

Comment: `all.parent().not('li.coin-profile').find('span')` finds always the same three elements, and `.data()` gets the data from the first of them. There's nothing there that would target a specific element.

Comment: Oh, you mean `.data()` only works on the first `span`?

Comment: Like I said, if you have multiple elements it only gets data from the first of them. You have to loop through and check each individually, or even better, don't store logic in the UI in the first place.

Comment: Can you provide a better way to do it in an answer, please?

Comment: You already have variables `sort` and `order`. Just use them to store the current state instead of DOM element data attributes.

Comment: So I need to store the three `span` data attributes separately then check if they're set.

Comment: Uh, no. There's only two states so you only need two variables. The other stores which item is selected, the other the sort direction.

Comment: Hmm but I only need a condition: if ... OR (this is first column AND any of the other three columns spans have data-sortby)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JJJ for finding the problem:

> `all.parent().not('li.coin-profile').find('span')` finds always the same three elements, and `.data()` gets the data from the first of them.

So [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) is only returning the attribute for the first match in the set of matched elements. Reading the docs, it clearly states it:

> Description: Return the value at the named data store for the first element in the jQuery collection, as set by data(name, value) or by an HTML5 data-* attribute.

To workaround this, I've decided to use [.filter()](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)[.length](https://api.jquery.com/length/):

```
isSet = all.parent().not('li.coin-profile').find('span')
        .filter(function() { return $(this).data('sortby') }).length
```